# Synchronize MySQL with updated Data only

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

Hello guyz I am trying to synchronize 2 database from my localhost and hosting. but with the condition that only last changed record will be updated for both local and hosted.

Example

Local:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
Data1r1 Data2r1 Data3r1         Data5r1
Data1r2         Data1r2 Data1r2 Data1r2
```

Hosted:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
Data1r1         Data3r1 Data4r1 
Data1r2 Data1r2 Data1r2 Data1r2
```

After filling up the missing data, both local and hosted will be like this

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
Data1r1 Data2r1 Data3r1 Data4r1 Data5r1
Data1r2 Data1r2 Data1r2 Data1r2 Data1r2
```

Question: What is the easiest and best way to do it? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many ways to do this.

> 1. First way is when data is change in particular table at that you can set a api call or event from localhost to hosted DB with that
>    updated data and edit the data based on id of that table row.
> 2. There is another way of doing this by cron job in regualar interval from localhost to hosted DB and vice versa.